# Android Slider/SeekBar Increment values

Tags: android, slider, seekbar

I am using a `slider` in android. The `slider` is being used to capture a percentage so min value is 0% and the max value is 100%. I have written the code to do so. I now wish to increment/decrement the slider by 1% and I also wish to write the actual value to a `SQLite` DB. I am not outputting the value to an `EditText`, I just need to know how to obtain the value from the slider and I am struggling to find documentation that I understand.

Please look at the method below. Can anyone please assist as I have no idea how to get this done.

Thank you all in advance.

```
private static void pebbleTypeHandlerPercentage(Pebble pebble, LinearLayout layout, Context context, String key, PData value)
{
    int id = getNextId();
    getLabel(layout, context, value);

    SeekBar seekBar = new SeekBar(context);
    seekBar.setMax(100);
    seekBar.setId(id);
    seekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser)
        {
        }

        @Override
        public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar)
        {

        }

        @Override
        public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar)
        {

        }
    });

    layout.addView(seekBar);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well to get the value that the progress bar is current set to you can use the onProgressChanged method in the listener. The "progress" value is what the current value of the progress bar. The boolean "fromUser" can be used to determine if you updated the value with setProgress or the user changed the value by dragging the thumb. Depending on what it is you are trying to accomplish you can ignore the value if its changed from the user with a simple if statement:

```
if(fromUser){`
`return;
}
```

Now, to avoid to much updating on the UI thread you could either use a Handler to capture and post a position changed from the onProgressChanged method or just save the value of progress from that method to some outside variable and do the update on the "onStopTrackingTouch" method